# Is SprintAir listed on any flight search engines?

Tags: flight-search-engines

There's this small, Polish airline [SprintAir](http://sprintair.eu).
Is there a way to find a flight search engine that would know about its flights, and include them in separate-tickets itinerary, like Skyscanner or Kiwi do?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Kayak.com is able to find their flights:

[image: sprintair kayak]

However the prices are not shown correctly and you have to go to the official website to book tickets.